# Get URL-Parameter in Javascript doesn't work with urlencoded '&'

Tags: javascript, jquery, url-encoding

I wanna read an get-parameter from the URL in Javascript. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery-or-how-to-get-query-string-values-in-js)

```
var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
        sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
        sParameterName,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

        if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
};
```

The problem is, that my paramter is this:

> iFZycPLh%Kf27ljF5Hkzp1cEAVR%oUL3$Mce&@XFcdHBb*CRyKkAufgVc32!hUni

I already made urlEncode, so its this:

> iFZycPLh%25Kf27ljF5Hkzp1cEAVR%25oUL3%24Mce%26%40XFcdHBb*CRyKkAufgVc32!hUni

But still, if I call the **getUrlParameter()** function, I just get this as result:

> iFZycPLh%Kf27ljF5Hkzp1cEAVR%oUL3$Mce

Does anyone know how I can fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `decodeURIComponent` on `sParameterName[0]` and `sParameterName[1]` instead of on the whole of `search.substring(1))`.

(i.e. on the *components* of it)

```
var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1),
        sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
        sParameterName,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

        var key = decodeURIComponent(sParameterName[0]);
        var value = decodeURIComponent(sParameterName[1]);

        if (key === sParam) {
            return value === undefined ? true : value;
        }
    }
};
```

This is mentioned in zakinster's comment on the answer you link to.

Comment: Thank you very much!!  Oh, I didn't read that comment from Zakinster. A mistake on my side. *ups*